# ToolTip on ListView SubItem is not shown

Tags: c#, .net, listview, tooltip

I am unable to show tooltips on ListView subitems. Involved implementation is:

```
ListView sqlView = new ListView() { Dock = DockStyle.Fill, View = View.Details, MultiSelect = true, FullRowSelect = true, HeaderStyle = ColumnHeaderStyle.Nonclickable, GridLines = true };
...
sqlView.ShowItemToolTips = true;
sqlView.MouseMove += sqlView_MouseMove;
...
// filled in foreach, don't worry it's correct here ;)
item.SubItems[columnIndex].Text = "✔";
item.SubItems[columnIndex].Tag = ("via: '" + sqlEntry.Login + "'");
```

Mouse event handler method:

```
void sqlView_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    ListView sqlView = ((ListView)sender);

    ListViewItem item = sqlView.GetItemAt(e.X, e.Y);
    ListViewHitTestInfo info = sqlView.HitTest(e.X, e.Y);

    if (item != null && info.SubItem != null && info.SubItem.Tag != null) 
    {
        ToolTip tt = new ToolTip();
        //tt.ShowAlways = true; - no effect
        //tt.Active = true;     - no effect

        tt.SetToolTip(sqlView, (String)info.SubItem.Tag);                
    }
}
```

Events are firing. Subitems Tags are filled properly. No Tooltip shown. Why?

Thx for help.

Answer (score 0):

Don't create a new `ToolTip()` each time through. Just create one and reuse it.